# Moment of image into center of blank image (Python, OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv

This is my problem.
I try to copy this image (20x20):
[image] into a new one created by code (28x28 blank canvas) with precise position. What I am trying to do is to set the violet point of source image centered into a new (canvas) image.
This is my code to do it:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

# Read images : src image will be cloned into dst
im = cv2.imread(os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\cube.png'))
obj = cv2.imread(os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\testCV.png'))

# Create an all white mask
mask = 255 * np.ones(obj.shape, obj.dtype)

# The location of the center of the src in the dst
center = (int(10), int(13))

# Seamlessly clone src into dst and put the results in output
normal_clone = cv2.seamlessClone(obj, im, mask, center, cv2.NORMAL_CLONE)

# Write results
cv2.imwrite(os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\fin.png'), normal_clone)
```

and this is the output : [image]

How do you see is not perfect there is some white in the right part and cause me some problems, i know the problem is the "mask", i try to modify it, but when i change 1 thing the code doesn't work. 
Do you know other ways to do the same think or maybe i only need to modify this.

Desired output should be like this example [image], centered according the reequest.

Thanks

Comment: Please post all your image `cube.png` and `testCV.png", so we can reproduce  the question.

Comment: cube.png is a white canvas (28x28) -  it's saved as image. testCV it's the image with violet point (this poitn is the mean area of black pixels in the image)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is not my code, i found it into another question, i try it and work very well.
This is the code:

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np

def findCenter(img):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    th, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    _, cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    M = cv2.moments(cnts[0])
    cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
    return (cX, cY)

img1 = cv2.imread("Path of the image you want to copy")
img2 = cv2.imread("Path of the image you want to use like a backgroud")

pt1 = findCenter(img1)
pt2 = findCenter(img2)

## (2) Calc offset
dx = (pt1[0] - pt2[0])
dy = (pt1[1] - pt2[1])

h, w = img2.shape[:2]

dst = img1.copy()
dst[dy:dy + h, dx:dx + w] = img2

cv2.imwrite(path + roi, dst)
```

This is the original answer:
[Match center of two images (OpenCV, Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48280828/match-center-of-two-images-opencv-python)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my result using numpy and OpenCV:

> 1. Find the coords in object
> 2. Calc the moment center of the object's coords
> 3. Calc the moment center offset (from src to dst)
> 4. Adjust the coord with offset
> 5. Do slice op

---

The result:

(1) object :

[image]

(2) cross background:

[image]

(3) object on the cross background:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code where do you copy the image ad put into the canvas please?